# I can't convert an object column to int in python

Tags: python

I have a table `'users'` with a column `'Internet users'` containing numeric values but they're as type object. I need to convert them to int, but:

- When I try `users['Internet users'] = users['Internet users'].astype(int)` I get an error *"invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,427,647,786'"*
- When I try `pd.to_numeric(users['Internet users'],errors='coerce')` it runs but returns all values as null. I need all the numeric values.
- I've tried `users['Internet users'] =  int(float(users['Internet users']))` but returns an error *cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>*

How can I convert this column to int avoiding returning null values?

Comment: You can't convert strings with commas to `int`s then apparently. Also you can't use `int()` or `float()` on a list.

Comment: You should include example data with your [mre]. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: You might get away with just removing the commas, otherwise I've added two duplicate targets that show 1. how to use locale-based functions to convert values in a dataframe column, and 2. what the relevant function is when converting integers (`locale.atoi`).

Comment: `S = pd.Series(['1,427,647,786']);  print(S.str.replace(',','').astype(int))`